# Gravity Forms dynamic Confirmation not working with Session Variables

Tags: php, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

After form submission I check the value of the form field against an array of values. If there's a match, I set the session variables.

```
session_start();

add_action( 'gform_after_submission', 'validate_the_field', 10, 2 );
function validate_the_field( $entry, $form ) {

    $the_field= $entry["1"];
    if($the_field) {

        $all_fields = explode( ',', get_field('all_fields', 'options') );
        if ( in_array($the_field, $all_fields) ) {
            $_SESSION['authorized'] = 'authorized';
        }

    }
}
```

I am trying to display a dynamic confirmation messages based on the session variables but the result is always "You are not authorized".

```
add_filter( 'gform_confirmation', 'custom_confirmation', 10, 4 );
function custom_confirmation( $confirmation, $form, $entry, $ajax ) {

    if ( $_SESSION['authorized'] == 'authorized' ) {
        $confirmation = "You are authorized.";
    } else {
        $confirmation = "You are not authorized.";
    }
    return $confirmation;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `gform_after_submission` action is fired *after* the `gform_confirmation` filter. Try replacing it with the [`gform_entry_created`](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_entry_created/) action which fires before the confirmation filter.

For more details on the order that Gravity Forms hooks are triggered, see the Gravity Forms Hook Reference:

https://gravitywiz.com/gravity-forms-hook-reference/

Comment: Thanks Dave, I did realize that afterwards and moved the code to the gform_field_validation so I can prevent submission for the invalid entry. Thanks for the reply.